# click event of usecontrol inside gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, onclick, windows-store-apps

I have gridview with custom usercontrols.
Here's the XAML of the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App11.VideoPreview"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App11"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="250"
    d:DesignWidth="250">

    <Grid>
        <Button Height="250" Width="250" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Name="image1" Height="250" Width="250" Stretch="None"/>
                <Grid Margin="0,-74,0,0">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" Opacity="0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF5B5B5B" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBox1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Foreground="White" Padding="5"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

how can I capture the click event when the button is clicked inside gridview?
I tried `GridView_ItemClick`, `GridView1_SelectionChanged` in the .cs of the gridview page
I also tried `button_Click` in the .cs of the usercontrol page
Both didnt work for me. any idea why?

EDIT:
It did work. I just tried to change frame using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageName));`
I cant change frame from usercontrol, I had to send the current frame to the usercontrol in the build function and then change the frame, like this:

```
    Frame frame;
    public VideoPreview(Frame f)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        frame = f;
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        frame.Navigate(typeof(PlayVideo));
    }
```

Comment: You should consider sticking with the regular Button.Click event.

Comment: Ok, it does work. I try to do specific thing that isnt working > I try to change frame

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into MVVM pattern http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial and use Commands instead of events.

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeActionCommand}" />
```

This will make your code much cleaner and reliable.